# Can the qTranslateX-Plugin translate non-article text?

Tags: widgets, translation, multi-language, localization, plugin-qtranslate

I started using the [qTranslateX](https://qtranslatexteam.wordpress.com/) plugin for a bilingual Wordpress site, and I am very happy with how it translates posts and pages. However, there is some text on the site that was entered as part of a widget, and I need it to be bilingual too. Can this be done? If not with qTranslateX, what are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like adding content in this format in Widget title/text content.

[:en]My English Title[:fr]My French Title

and on echoing this.. q-translate will make them work .